Where to find list of connection profiles for OpenVPN in Ubuntu
I am trying to start an OpenVPN connection but when I run openvpn3 session-start --config filename
It responds with
---- More than one configuration profile was found with the given name

Where would I go to see the list of connection profiles so that I can get rid of one?
There's only one file in the directory that I am currently in so there's no duplicate files or anything like that. Another copy might exist somewhere on my machine but it's not in the current directory so I don't know how it would see it.

i'm assuming it's OpenVPN 3
to see the configs u can do
openvpn3 configs-list

to remove an unwanted config u can do
openvpn3 config-remove --config <profile-id>


The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Thank you, I'm able to see both of them now but I can't remove one for the same reason. Is there an option to remove all profiles?
